# No custom sites to move to

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, migration

I was experimenting around with different dialogs, and found that there are no other sites to (possibly) migrate questions to (except PLDI Meta), unlike Stack Overflow.

[image]

Is this because PLDI is still in beta?

Comment: I believe the migration destinations must be added manually, and we haven't discussed any yet. I could see ones to CS and maybe SO being useful, tho

Answer (score 8):

> Is this because PLDI is still in beta?

**Yes.** From [What is migration and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10250):

> Not every site has selectable migration paths; in particular, **beta sites**, recently-graduated sites, and Meta Stack Exchange **don't have any selectable sites** (other than the site's per-site meta, if applicable, and vice versa). On such sites, **only moderators can migrate questions** out of that site (as they can choose any site to migrate to).

Emphasis mine.

If you are very confident that a question ought to be migrated to another site, feel free to raise a moderator flag requesting that it be migrated. However, remember the guiding principles:

- Check for cross-posts.
- Don’t migrate for the sake of migration.
- Be familiar with the destination site.
- **Don’t migrate crap.**
- When in doubt, **don’t migrate**.

Comment: Dah, ninja'd! I was just in the process of writing basically the exact same thing!

Comment: Fortunately (or unfortunately, depending on your perspective) there are no imaginary internet points to steal on Meta :)

Comment: Haha true :p. Good call including the migration guidelines - I wasn't thinking to include those.